# datePicker jquery UI - not showing on normal load but loading on form post

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to put 2 datePickers jquery UI. The error: when I load the page, the datePickers are not showing. But if I post the form it will display them.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//...
if ($_POST){
    $dateFrom=getInput('dateFrom').' 00:00:00';
    $dateTo=getInput('dateTo').' 23:59:59';
    $defDate=explode('-',getInput('dateFrom'));
    $defDate=$defDate[1].'/'.$defDate[2].'/'.$defDate[0];
    $employeeID=getInput('employeeID');
}else{
    $dateFrom=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 day'));
    $dateTo=date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59';
    $defDate=date('m/d/Y',strtotime('-1 day'));
    $employeeID=0;
}

//================================== calendar widget ==================================
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(function() {';
echo '  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 0,
                changeMonth: true,
                defaultDate: "'.$defDate.'",
                changeYear: true,';
echo "  altField: '#datepickera',altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});";
echo '  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 0,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,';
echo "  altField: '#datepickerb',altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});";
echo '});';
echo '</script>';

echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td width="250">From Date<input type="text" id="datepickera" name="dateFrom" value="" /><br /><div id="datepicker1"></div></td>';
echo '<td width="250">To Date<input type="text" id="datepickerb" name="dateTo" value="" /><br /><div id="datepicker2"></div></td>';
echo '<td>'. __('Choose Employee','j-v3').':<br /><select name="employeeID" /><option value="0">--- All Employees ---</option>';
echo '</select> <input type="submit" value="Get Data" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
//...
?>
```

I'm using jquery 1.6.2 & jquery-ui 1.8.15

Help please. How to always show the datePickers?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @arshad i'm asking here because the problem can't be solved by the readme. So nobody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Changing the script into this does not work:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {';
```

But using this code, it works

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() {';
```

The different of them after searching on google is that the 1st one is run after the DOM is ready, the document doesn't really necessary to be ready. The 2nd one is run after all parts of the document are ready, thus takes longer time.

In my case only the 2nd approach is working, it's slower but it works.